# Производительность Jenkins

Tags: производительность, jenkins

Имеется 2 сервера. На обоих запускаю `java -jar jenkins.war`.

На одном - работает без нареканий.

На втором:

- картинки/иконки грузятся в разнабой;
- не могу сохранить конфиг, перенаправляет на `http://jenkins/configSubmit`, выдаёт ошибку 400, изменения не сохраняет.

Нагрузки на процессор, память - нет.
Не понимаю, с чего начать разбор проблемы.

Comment: проверьте, что в конфигурации jenkins url стоит верный, судя по всему, где-то потерялось верное указание протокола `http://`. Исправить это лучше всего руками в xml-файлах.

Comment: Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL стоит верный. Меня сильно смущает, что не отрисовываются, например, все иконки (в столбце слева на главной странице, в меню Manage Jenkins). Точнее отрисовываются, но каждый раз разные. При этом, по ощущениям - сам веб-интерфейс работает резво. Попробовал снизить количество экзекуторов до 0. JDK разных версий брал - изменений не вижу.

Comment: верный - это с корректной схемой (http://)?

Comment: Разобрался. Между сегментами сети стоит некий фильтр трафика. Организовал работу через https - все проблемы ушли. Симптомы для тех, кто столкнётся с проблемой - случайное отображение рисунков, случайная разметка при обновлении страницы. При этом работает всё быстро, страницы прорисовываются быстро.

Comment: я бы написал полноценным ответом, до комментариев не всякий доберется взглядом